# I want show multiple recyclerview from json array object filtering

Tags: android, arrays, json, kotlin, android-recyclerview

In my app, i have a sample JSON. I can create recyclerview using this sample JSON. But I want another recyclerview using this sample json object.
For better understanding please see the code below

Sample.json

```
[
{
"Id": "1",
"Title": "Guardians of the Galaxy Vol. 2",
 "Year": 2017,
 "Runtime": "136 min",
 "Genre": "Sci-Fi",
  "Director": "James Gunn",
 },
 {
  "Id": "2",
  "Title": "Jhon wick",
  "Year": 2014,
  "Runtime": "148 min",
  "Genre": "Action",
  "Director": "James fosling",
   },
   {
   "Id": "3",
   "Title": "raid",
   "Year": 2016,
   "Runtime": "120 min",
    "Genre": "Action",
    "Director": "Chang Lee",
    }
    ]
```

The question is i want another recyclerview using json object "Genre". i mean in this json array each json arrary have 6 object then i want to use Genre to create a new recyclerview.suppose there is three movie and it's show a recyclerview.Then i want a new recyclerview which show only those movie which genre is "action".That's mean jhon wick and raid together create a new recyclerview.

How can i do that?

Comment: use map to create a group and show into reyclerView

Comment: please, explain or give me some example code, Thank you

Comment: So you want to filter the Action genre objects into another array?

Comment: yes,i want.the this array shows another recyclerview

Answer (score 0):

first you have to parse this JSON,
and create List of Strings for example

```
List<String> genres = new ArrayList<>();
```

and then while parsing the JSON create Hash map of String and list of Movies for example.

```
 HashMap<String, List<Movie>> response = new HashMap<>();
```

now for each element in your JSON get the value of Genre key and check if this value presented in hash map or not,

- if not presented then get the List at this key and add the current movie to it and then add the value of genre to genres List.
- if value already presented in hash map then just get the List of movies at this key and add the current movie to it.

you can do the checks by the following:

```
response.containsKey("value")
List<Movie> movies = response.get("value");
```

and then now you can populate the genres list to another recycler view and once user choose element from it you can take the List of movies from response hash map and populate it to movies recycler view.